# how to revert to desktop version of chat?

Tags: support

I accidentally clicked on the mobile link below:

[image]

And when I join the chat room, it appears optimized for mobile browser viewing:

[image]

How do I revert to the desktop experience?

Answer (score 1):

Right, I went to the hamburger menu top left, and, clicked on Full site...